# How to put 2 boxplot in one graph in R without additional libraries?

Tags: r, graph, boxplot

I have this kind of dataset

```
Defect.found       Treatment         Program

      1             Testing          Counter
      1             Testing        Correlation
      0            Inspection        Counter
      3             Testing        Correlation
      2            Inspection        Counter
```

I would like to create two boxplotes, one boxplot of detected defects per program and one boxplot of detected defects per technique but in one graph.

Meaning having:

```
boxplot(exp$Defect.found ~ exp$Treatment)
boxplot(exp$Defect.found ~ exp$Program)
```

In a joined graph.

Searching on Stackoverflow I was able to create it but with lattice library typing:

```
bwplot(exp$Treatment + exp$Program ~ exp$Defects.detected)
```

but i would like to know if its possible to create the graph without additional libraries like `ggplot` and `lattice`

Comment: see the second last example in `?boxplot`, use `at` and `boxwex` and `add`

Comment: I'm didnt understand you wean't, i must add im pretty new to R language and i dont know all the parameters etc. But thanks anyway ill start to search on how to implement those you gave me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prepare the plot window to receive two plots in one row and two columns (default is obviously one row and one column):

```
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
```

My suggestion is to avoid using the word `exp`, because it is already used for the exponential function. Use for instance `mydata`.

*Defects found against treatment* (`frame = F` suppresses the external box):

```
with(mydata, plot(Defect.found ~ Treatment, frame = F))
```

*Defects found against program* (`ylab = NA` suppresses the y label because it is already shown in the previous plot):

```
with(mydata, plot(Defect.found ~ Program, frame = F, ylab = NA))
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what i was searching for, I would give you more points if I could just because of the code comment and explanation!